# ajax login success data but not redirect to index page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to validate login form using ajax success response is working but if all goods it should be redirect to index page but it's not working , i don't understand what's wrong please help. thanks in advance..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var response;
        $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.alert-box').html('<div id="loading" style="margin: 0 auto;" > 
        </div>');
        var action = 'ajax_validation';
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"do_login.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, username:username, password:password},
            success:function(data){
              response = data;
              if(response === 1){
                window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
              }else{
                $('.alert-box').addClass("alert alert-warning");
                $('.alert-box').html(response);
              }
                }
            });
       });
    });
```

above these ajax request
this is action page code
    include('includes/db.php');

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])){

    $check_username = $_POST['username'];
    $check_password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($check_username) && empty($check_password)){
        echo "Please fill all field";
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '{$check_username}' AND password = '{$check_password}' ";  
        $select_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        if(!$select_query){
        die("QUERY FAILED".mysqli_error($select_query));
        }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($select_query)==0){
            echo "Username or password are incorrect!";
        }else{
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_query)) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['email'];
                echo $row['email'];
            }
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: your response is `echo $row['email'];` so you should change it to `echo 1;`

Comment: Your issue may be that you're not echoing 1 when that's what your AJAX response is looking for. Try echoing 'success' instead of `echo $row['email'];`, then in your AJAX call, your if statement can be `if(response =='success'){`

Comment: why are u echo email? do u want to show this email? u need to use echo 1; but outside the while loop, second, i hope u are using `session_start()` at top level

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your resposne you are echoing

```
 echo $row['email'];
```

This should be:

```
 echo 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are checking if value is 1 in ajax:

```
success:function(data){
      response = data;
      if(response === 1){ //<- there you are checking if your echo is 1 but you are trying to echo $row['email']; 
         window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
      }else{
         $('.alert-box').addClass("alert alert-warning");
         $('.alert-box').html(response);
      }
 }
```

change your echo from `$row['email']` to `1`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is response checking condition in ajax success.
You're checking if a string (email or error message) is equal and the same type of 1.

```
...
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data){
              response = data;
              if(response === 1){
...
```

You can use a json response with status/error code:

```
...
success:function(data){
              response = JSON.parse(data);
              if(response.status === 1){
                window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
              }else{
                $('.alert-box').addClass("alert alert-warning");
                $('.alert-box').html(response.data);
              }
                }
...
```

```
$check_username = $_POST['username'];
$check_password = $_POST['password'];
$res = array('status'=> 0, 'data' => '');
if(empty($check_username) && empty($check_password)){
    $res['status'] = 0;
    $res['data'] = "Please fill all field";
}else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '{$check_username}' AND password = '{$check_password}' ";  
    $select_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    if(!$select_query){
      $res['status'] = 0;
      $res['data'] = "QUERY FAILED".mysqli_error($select_query);
      echo json_encode($res);
      return;
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($select_query)==0){
      $res['status'] = 0;
      $res['data'] = "Username or password are incorrect!";
    }else{
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_query)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['email'];
            $res['status'] = 1;
            $res['data'] = "".$row['email'];
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

In addition i suggest to put only the username in query where condition and check if the password match with php.

Comment: and what about data type in ajax request?

Comment: Yes, i miss dataType, sorry.